# CanCan Defining ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

Is there a way not to define equal ? but includes?

```
can :read, Project, :category => { :visible => true }

can :read, Project, :category => { :map(&:user_id) => { include(user.id) } }
```

Using CanCan and ruby on rails...

Thanks

Comment: can you give me some examples?? according to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what exactly you want to accomplish. Based on @apneadiving comment you can do something like:

```
can :read, Project do |project|
  project.category.user_ids.include?(user.id)
end
```

For more information read [this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities#hash-of-conditions) section of CanCan wiki.

Comment: if I want specific project? which is @project also same?

Comment: That works for any project instance. Maybe you will find this gem helpful: https://github.com/EppO/rolify